# Cargar imágenes en la web con javascript resulta mas lento de lo que pensaba

Tags: javascript

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


 $("#test").on('click', function() {

    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            src  : 'images/_pic01.jpg',
            opts : {
                caption : '',
                thumb   : 'images/JPEG/min-01.jpg'
            }
        },
        {
            src  : 'images/_pic02.jpg',
            opts : {
                caption : '',
                thumb   : 'images/JPEG/min-02.jpg'
            }
        }
         ], {
        loop : true,
        hash : "test" 
    });
/* Hasta 24 imagenes total*/
});
});
```

```html
/* He añadido este script de abajo en el 'HEAD' y la carga ha mejorado.*/

<script>
window.onload = function() {

 setTimeout(function() {

  // reference to <head>
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

  // a new CSS
  var css = document.createElement('link');
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.rel  = "stylesheet";
  css.href = "http://domain.tld/preload.css";

  // a new JS
  var js  = document.createElement("script");
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src  = "http://domain.tld/preload.js";

  // preload JS and CSS
  head.appendChild(css);
  head.appendChild(js);

  // preload image
  new Image().src = "http://domain.tld/preload.jpg";

 }, 1000);

};
</script>





<a id="test" href="javascript:;">
    <button type="button" value="" class="btn bg-primary bg-gris btn-lg btn-block">Ver Galería</button>
   </a>
```

Mi galería de imágenes se carga muy despacio, ¿se pueden pre-cargar las imágenes antes de verlas??. Gracias.
[Galeria de imágenes, con fancybox](http://www.fcomp.es/index.html)

Comment: igual esto puede ayudarte: [Preload images with javascript + css](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, realiza el [tour] del sitio. Debes realizar preguntas en base a [ask]

Comment: El mayor problema es que acabo de empezar...

Comment: Gracias  [Athos Oc], acabo de añadir el script del enlace que me pasaste, y ha sido fantástico.

Comment: ...siento mucho haber metido la pata, estoy tan nervioso que no se que responder. Pero intentaré enmendar. Como ya escribí en la pregunta, mi página web se cargaba muy despacio, Athos Oc me pasó un enlace para una posible solución. y así lo hice; a partir de ahí la página se carga mejor. Ahora voy a ver si lo se explicar mejor.